# window.open opens two popup windows in IE

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I'm getting a really strange behaviour in IE8.

I have a simple javascript function to create a popup window. The popup window is created ok, but the parent window forwards to a completely blank window that just prints [object]. I have to hit the back button to get back to the original page.

```
<a href='javascript:window.open("http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=In&searchOption=entry_idiom","Dictionary","width=500, height=500")' target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

There is no problem in Chrome, just IE. How can I get rid of this annoying behaviour?

Comment: I wonder if you need to return false from your click code to prevent the default handling of the href?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is Internet Explorer executes the code as expected, but also displays the return value of `window.open` in a new document. Since `window.open` returns an object reference to the new document, this gets converted to a string - `[object Object]` - and is displayed.

To remedy this, you can add `return false` to prevent the browser returning anything.

```
<a href='javascript:window.open("http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=In&searchOption=entry_idiom","Dictionary","width=500, height=500"); return false' target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

**Edit** - See OP's comment below this answer. The solution was to move the JavaScript to an `onclick` attribute, and to change the `target` attribute to be the same as the popup name.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='window.open("http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=In&searchOption=entry_idiom","Dictionary","width=500, height=500");' target="Dictionary">Click me</a>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the popup window was not the specified width and height, and showed the error message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that. I've added a new solution - let me know if that works any better.

Comment: OK. I got it. Now I have identical behaviour in Chrome and IE. It's based on your Edit, but slightly amended. Here it is:
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='window.open("h ttp://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=cat&searchOption=entry_idiom","Dictionary","width=500, height=500");' target='Dictionary'>Hello</a>

The key to the full solution was to name the window in the 'open' method and set the target of the anchor tag to that name... in my case I named it 'dictionary'.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't spot that! Well done, you deserve the rep more than I do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/Pf8Rw/

**HTML**

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="open-popup">test</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $('.open-popup').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=300,height=200');
    });
```

*Note : Tested in chrome and IE 8*

Comment: The link you gave me (jsfiddle) displays perfectly in chrome, but is broken all over the place in IE8.

Comment: Did you notice that this code doesnt break in IE 8 but the JsFiddle' website does. The above code works perfectly in IE 8 see this http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/Pf8Rw/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Track outbound links. Add the following javascript code to index.html file:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicky_custom = clicky_custom || {};
  clicky_custom.outbound_disable = 1;
</script>`